# Radix UI with React.js and NOT Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radix-ui

I simply want to work on a React project and I want to use Radix UI (Theme).
But when I tried to install and import, it says this message below

[image]

How can I fix it?

All I did was written this code

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { Flex, Text, Button } from "@radix-ui/themes";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Flex direction="column" gap="2">
          <Text>Hello from Radix Themes :)</Text>
          <Button>Let's go</Button>
        </Flex>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I just did `npx create-react-app`,  `npm install @radix-ui/themes`, import `Flex, Text, Button` and that's it.

Comment: This looks like a build issue. What stack are you using? This could be a webpack/babel issue, or it could be a tsconfig issue, or it could be that you simply need to restart your server after installing radix. Hard to pinpoint the problem without more information.

Comment: React.js and that's it 
I just created a new project and did 
npx create-react-app, npm install @radix-ui/themes, import Flex, Text, Button and that's it.

Comment: CRA == Stack. Did you install typescript with CRA?

Comment: Nope I didn't use TypeScript, should I?

Comment: Well, the error's complaining about source maps from .tsx files, which are TypeScript-enabled JSX files, so either that or figure out how to install a plain JavaScript version of radix.

Comment: Please avoid `create-react-app`, it's been orphaned by the React Devs. Use Vite instead.

Comment: What do you mean by orphaned?

Comment: @SpicyyRiice abandoned